# How do I remove the text of the app tile?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I've created an icon for my app that also contains the name of the app. So having the Text in the tile itself is redundant.

Is there a way I can remove it? I still want the text in the main app list too - just want the default text while the icon is pinned not to be there :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open the `WMAppManifest.xml` file and set the `<Title>` to a whitespace under `<Tokens><PrimaryToken>`